# How to validate textbox in angularjs 2 if it contains values or not on click of button

Tags: angular

As I am new to Angularjs 2, I am facing some issues in validating textbox.The requirement is that on click of button, the textbox should be populated with some value, but if it does not get populated then error should be shown through styling. Is this possible as I know that in Angularjs 1.x, we can check by pristine/dirty properties.
Can someone provide some code block?

Thanks.

Comment: You are probably looking for some form validation: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Answer (score -2):

First of all, there is no such thing as angularjs2, now it's just named Angular, and in that way you should refer to it.

Secondly to achieve such functionality you have to use `ReactiveForms` it's a complex form controller. I prefer to read whole [guide](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). Shortly reactive forms does have `pristine/dirty` state but it also comes with complexity and a lot of work to implement this in correct way.